# Reference a field from a different dataset in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I need some help creating an expression in a dataset called "ReportData" that references a field from a different dataset called "Contracts".

I've tried the expression builder, and created the following expression:

```
=IIf((First(Fields!Product.Value, "Contracts")="Loan"),
 cdbl(Sum(Fields!Provision.Value, "Contracts")),
 cdbl(0))
```

This returns 0, which is correct, because First(Fields!Product.Value, "Contracts")="Loan" is indeed false, but I want to evaluate the "entire" Product Field, and not just the first value.

Answer (score 1):

These expressions assume the current dataset scope is `DatasetA`.

This is a basic sum from `DatasetB` that will show if the value in `DatasetA` is "some text". Not sure if this will do what you need.

```
=IIf(Fields!Field1.Value = "some text", Sum(Fields!Field2.Value, "DatasetB"), 0)
```

This looks at the first value in `DatasetB` and does a sum based on that. This seems closest to the pseudocode you presented.

```
=IIf(First(Fields!Field1.Value, "DatasetB") = "some text", Sum(Fields!Field2.Value, "DatasetB"), 0)
```

This is the lookup version which returns the `Field2` value in `DatasetB` based on a value (`Field1`) in `DatasetA` (current scope) matching a value (`Field1`) in `DatasetB`. I added this in case you need it for some reason while troubleshooting.

```
=Lookup(Fields!Field1.Value, Fields!Field1.Value, Fields!Field2.Value, "DatasetB")
```

Maybe a little more than you need, but hopefully one of these works for you.

EDIT:

```
=IIf(Lookup("Loan", Fields!Product.Value, Fields!Provision.Value.ToString().Length, "Contracts") > 0, Sum(Fields!Provision.Value, "Contracts"), 0)
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but the expression always evaluates to false and returns 0.

Comment: I included 3 expressions, which one did you try? If you tried all of them, and they all are not working, are you sure the data is what you expect between the 2 datasets? Can a match ever return true?

Comment: I tried all the expressions. Under the scope of Dataset B,
=Sum(Fields!Field2.Value) returns 250.

My goal is to create en expression under the scope of Dataset A that returns that same value. However, under the scope of Dataset A, all your suggestions return 0.

Comment: I see you updated the question. Does the first `Fields!Product.Value` from the Contracts dataset actually equal "Loan"?

Comment: No, it does not. The First function is added automatically when I try to build my expression. I have not found a good way of evaluating the "entire" Contact field, and not just the first value.

Comment: I have added a new expression that may help you. Give it a try.

Comment: I also want to replace "Loan" with "Leasing" and get different results, so it's not to do with if the string length is greater than 0.

Comment: You can replace that string with a field value. Plus, this is checking the length of the provision, not the product. So, if there is something returned in the lookup, you show the summary. Good luck with all of this.

Comment: Your expression returns the sum of all Provisions. I want it to return the sum of Provisions ONLY where Product is "Loan".

Comment: What you need cannot be done without some extra Code in the report; something like this: https://github.com/OzLocke/SSRSAggLookup

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, use the expression builder!

Within the properties of the element you wish to modify:

1. Click
2. You will see Datasets within the list of categories.
3. From there you can select any field from any dataset.
4. Build your expression within this window!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IIF(
SUM(IIF(Fields!Product.Value="Loan",1,0),"Contracts")>0,
CDbl(Sum(Fields!Provision.Value, "Contracts")),
Cdbl(0)
)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Product.Value="Loan",Fields!Provision.Value,0),"Contracts")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your expression returns the sum of all Provisions. I want it to return the sum of Provisions ONLY where Product is "Loan".

Comment: Your update uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.

Comment: @Simon, In that case describe the data types of your data, it is impossible guess that with the short description in your question.

Comment: Product is a text field, whereas Provision is an integer field. It looks as if your suggestion tries to aggregate text and integer.

Comment: @Simon, Did you try the expression? It is aggregating only provision values based on if control.